# Autosave jupyter workspace

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab, workspace

Is it possible to autosave jupyter lab workspace?
This doesn't seem available in the [docs](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/urls.html#url-workspaces-ui).

Comment: It does autosave for me. I think that you may need to provide more details.

Comment: This quite an old question. But I really don't know what's the answer here. I would like to know if I can start a specific workspace by let's say firing a command like `jupyter-lab --workspace project1`. Then jupyter should autosave the opened tabs. So next time, when I fire the same command, I should get the exact workspace with all opened tabs.

Comment: I dabbled with some potential solutions on the internet, such as having separate port numbers for separate workspace. But none of that works. How ever I create a new  workspace, it is either blank or a clone (in sync) with already opened workspace. Not sure what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this it is very easy. Just need to specify the workspace in the jupyter-lab's address.
For example, if the port number is 8000,

For project1,

```
https://localhost:8000/lab/workspaces/project1
```

For project2,

```
https://localhost:8000/lab/workspaces/project1
```

In my experience, jupyter-lab auto-saves the workspaces, so when you close and reopen the address (tab in the web browser), the workspace will contain all the tabs as there were when you left them.

That's very convenient for managing different projects. I am bit ashamed that I never learnt about this during my past 3-4 years where I have used jupyter-lab almost everyday. In my experience, without this functionality, managing different projects can be is very tedious and messy.